# tshark filters in Centos 7

Tags: command-line, quoting, wireshark, tshark

I am working on some tshark filters , need to split a pcap on timebasis for particular SIP and DIP, I have tried editcap but it can go with time basis only I cannot pass IPADDRESS to editcap, I saw tshark can do this

```
[root@ids01 snort-1]# tshark -r snort.log.1518688921  -w /tmp/pcap_tshark.pcap -Y "(frame.time >= "" Feb 17, 2018 16:00:00"") && (frame.time <= ""Feb 17, 2018 16:01:00"") && ip.addr==192.0.0.7"
tshark: "17" was unexpected in this context
```

Please see bold one for error what is the issue with filters , I am using centos 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with usage of quotes, you need backslash to preserve double quote of the filter, try this:

```
tshark -r snort.log.1518688921  -w /tmp/pcap_tshark.pcap -Y '(frame.time >= "Feb 17, 2018 16:00:00") && (frame.time <= "Feb 17, 2018 16:01:00") && ip.addr==192.0.0.7'
```

or this which also permits to use variables instead of hard coded time values - for example inside a script:

```
dbeg="Feb 17, 2018 16:00:00"
dend="Feb 17, 2018 16:01:00"
tshark -r snort.log.1518688921  -w /tmp/pcap_tshark.pcap -Y "(frame.time >= \"${dbeg}\") && (frame.time <= \"${dend}\") && ip.addr==192.0.0.7"
```